# Replace individual symbols in a set

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a simplified way in JavaScript + Reg-Ex to replace all occurrences of each symbol in a set with its alternative symbol?

Example:

```
"Test: 1, 2, 3 and 1".replace("123", "ABC");
// we need to get: "Test: A, B, C and A";
```

I mean, is there any Reg-Ex trick to avoid a for-loop here? And anyway, what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Provisions:

1. In my task the set of symbols is usually very short (could even be 3 symbols) and it is static, not dynamic, very similar to the example shown.
2. Sometimes a symbol needs to be replaced with an empty '', i.e. removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build out your replacements using an Object Literal.

```
var map = {'1':'A', '2':'B', '3':'C'};
str = str.replace(/[123]/g, function(k) {
    return map[k];
});
```

Or create a custom function using a map for this:

```
function _replace(str, map) {
   var re = new RegExp('['+Object.keys(map).join('')+']','g');
   return str.replace(re, function(x) { return map[x] });
}
```

Comment: For making it more _dynamic_: `.replace(new RegExp('['+ Object.keys(map).join('') +']', 'g'), fn)`

Comment: A. Would you still do it this way, if you had just 3 symbols to replace? B. Would it still work, if one of the replacements were with '', i.e. removal?

Comment: Quite possibly, and I should have mentioned that some of the symbols may need to be replaced with '', i.e. removed - I just hope this doesn't invalidate my question.

Comment: @vitaly-t You can either add `{ '4' : '', .... }` to the object or use the `||` operator in the callback: `return map[k] || '';`

Comment: Do I take it right that it is impossible to do with just a single Reg-Ex operation?